# Ehcache set TTL while adding data

Tags: java, ehcache, dropwizard

I wanted to use Ehcache in my project. We are using DropWizard Framework. We are having a use case where we wanted to have a in memory cache which can have capability to store key and value with different TTLs. We found that in Ehcache, we can store the Key, value pair. But I am unable to found how to set the TTL for this. As I saw in ehcache.xml, we can set the time to live for entire cache. Is there a way to set the TTL on row level basis.

If possible, please provide an example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the `Element` to cache, simply call into `net.sf.ehcache.Element#setTimeToLive` before calling `net.sf.ehcache.Cache#put(net.sf.ehcache.Element)`.